# Grade Array Averager troubles

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am currently in an IT curriculum in college. Advance Visual Basic 2010 is a requirement however, I am not a programmer. I have been struggling to find my way through VB but this last assignment has me stumped.I am able to get the first name into the array and the 5 grades for that name . At that point, the loop will continue to ask for the next name and that names 5 grades and so on until the 4th name and grades are entered and then it should display all 4 names and grade averages in the listbox.

Here is the assignment...

Write a program that will input four students’ names and average five test grades for each student. The program should have an array for the students name and then a two-dimensional array for all their grades.
Your program should ask for the students name and then five test scores for that student.
Create a method that does the averaging and pass the arrays to that method. That method can also output the student name and average in a list box.
Call a method to figure up the average once you get all the grades. Do not figure it up as you get the information!! You’ll get a big ole zero if you do! Then have that same method output the results into the list box:

After 4 days of struggling with this, here is what I have come up with so far. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnNames_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNames.Click
        Dim NamesList(3) As String

        Dim GradeArray(4) As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim Sum As Integer
        Dim Avg As Integer

        For y = 0 To NamesList(3)
            NamesList(x) = InputBox("Enter student number " & y + 1 & "'s name:", "Enter a name")
        Next

        For y = 0 To GradeArray.Length - 1
            GradeArray(y) = InputBox("Enter grade number " & y + 1 & " for " & NamesList(0) & " in the box:", "Enter the grades")
        Next

        For Each item In GradeArray
            Sum = Sum + item
        Next

        Avg = Sum / 5

        lstAverages.Text = Avg.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: please give a (one) **specific** problem `here is what I have come up with so far` is not a problem.  we arent going to do it for you and cant know what you are stuck on without you detailing it.  That said, it will ask for 3 students, but only one set of Grades.  Set a breakpoint and watch each line execute and you will learn a lot about what happens vs what you **thought** would happen.

Comment: In addition to what @Plutonix said, you're missing a 2-dimensional array (per the assignment), and `For y = 0 To NamesList(3)` is one of those things that will fall under the category of "what happens vs what you **thought** would happen".

Comment: Tip: Set `Option Strict On` (always) you'll learn more, have fewer runtime errors, write better code and have that just-showered feeling all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had nothing else better to do, so I took up giving it a try... Also this includes per as you stated: 4 students - 5 grades each, array for students names and a 2D array to hold all their grades. There's a method that passes these to it and performs the averaging of the students grades and then spits them to a listbox as requested ... Happy Coding!

P.S. I didn't do any error handling either, you may want to add that or at least implement something to handle such cases ...

```
Public Class Form1

 Private arrStudents(3) As String 'Student's name array (4)
 Private arrScores(3, 4) As Integer 'Students scores (5 each)

'Start getting the data we need
Private Sub btnGetStudents_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetStudents.Click
    Dim strStudent As String = String.Empty
    Dim intScore As Integer = 0
    Dim intPlace As Integer = 0

    'Get the students name...
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrStudents.Length - 1
        Do Until strStudent <> String.Empty
            strStudent = InputBox("Please enter student's name: ", "Gather Student Grades")
        Loop
        arrStudents(i) = strStudent

        'Reset our variable...
        strStudent = String.Empty

        'Get the students grades...
        For s As Integer = 0 To arrScores.Length - 1

            Do Until intScore > 0
                intScore = CInt(InputBox("Please enter student's scores: ", "Gather Student Scores"))
            Loop

            If (intPlace = 4 AndAlso i = arrStudents.Length) Then
                intPlace = 0
                arrScores(i, s) = intScore
                intScore = 0
            ElseIf intPlace = 4 Then
                intPlace = 0
                arrScores(i, s) = intScore
                intScore = 0
                Exit For
            Else
                arrScores(i, intPlace) = intScore
                intPlace += 1
            End If

            'Reset our variables...
            intScore = 0
        Next
    Next

    'Calculate and output the data to the listbox...
    GetStudentAverages(arrStudents, arrScores)

End Sub

'Function to average per student grades and then display them all in the listbox...
Private Sub GetStudentAverages(ByVal arStudent As Array, ByVal arScore As Array)
    Dim strStudentData As String = String.Empty
    Dim intAverage As Integer = 0
    Dim intPlace As Integer = 0

    'Start averaging the students scores and then add them to the listbox...
    For i As Integer = 0 To arStudent.Length - 1
        For g As Integer = 0 To arScore.Length - 1
            If intPlace = arStudent.Length Then
                intAverage += arScore(i, intPlace)
                Exit For
            Else
                intAverage += arScore(i, intPlace)
                intPlace += 1
            End If
        Next
        intAverage = CInt(intAverage / 5)
        intPlace = 0

        'Output the student information...
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Student: " & arStudent(i).ToString & " Average: " & intAverage.ToString)
        intAverage = 0
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Can to explain downvote? It helps as to why, that way I can justify what's wrong, thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much to anyone who took a moment to look at my request. Thanks specifically to Mr CoDeXeR. I really appreciate the work on this request. This helped a great deal. I had to make a few minor adjustments but without your input I would still be struggling.